# SOAP attachment not reaching server side

Tags: java, soap

I am using SAAJ at the client side for sending a soap request. I am also attaching a random binary string as an attachment to the SOAP request, using this API.

```
soapMessage.addAttachment(attachment);
```

When I sniff this request through wireshark, I can see my attachment outside the `<SoapEnv>`,
but when this request reaches the client side (which is implemented using the JBoss libraries), I only get the message and not the attachment.

I have not specificed anything in the WSDL related to the attachments.

I can't figure out what can be the problem.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Your title says "not reaching the server side", and your description says "not reaching the client side". Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you send along the right Content-Type, Content-Transfer-Encoding and Content-ID header values?

http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/AttachmentsProfile-1.0.html#Value-space_of_Content-Id_Header

Maybe post the generated soap-message